# inner classes in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, inner-classes

I wonder why smalltalk doesn't make use of java-style inner class. This mechanism effectively allows you to define a new instance of a new class, on-the-fly, where you need it, when you need it. It comes handy when you need an object conforming to some specific protocol but you don't want to create a normal class for it, because of its temporary and local nature being very implementation specific.
As far I know, it could be done easily, since syntax for subclassing is standard message sending. And you can pass self to it so it has the notion of the "outer" object. The only issue is anonymousity - the class should not be present in object browser and must be garbage collected when no instances of it exit.
The question is: Has anyone thought of this?

Comment: You should have a look at Newspeak and Beta, or these papers: "Modules as Objects in Newspeak" and "Virtual classes: a powerful mechanism in object-oriented programming". That is the real power of nested classes! Anonymous nested classes in java are just an afterthought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really two answers here:

**1 - Yes, it is not hard to create anonymous classes** that automatically get garbage collected. In Squeak they are called "uniclasses" because the typical use case is for adding methods to a single object. Systems that use this are for example Etoys and Tweak (although in Etoys the classes are actually put into the SystemDict for historic reasons). Here's some Squeak code I recently used for it:

```
newClass := ClassBuilder new
    newSubclassOf: baseClass
    type: baseClass typeOfClass
    instanceVariables: instVars
    from: nil.
baseClass removeSubclass: newClass.
^newClass
```

Typically, you would add a convenience method to do this. You can can then add methods, and create an instance, and when all instances are gone, the class will be gc'ed too.

Note that in Java, the class object is not gc'ed - an inner class is compiled exactly like a regular class, it's only hidden by the compiler. In contrast, in Smalltalk this all happens at runtime, even the compiling of new methods for this class, which makes it comparatively inefficient. There is a much better way to create anonymous precompiled behavior, which brings us to answer 2:

**2 - Even though it's not hard, it's rarely used in Smalltalk.** The reason for that is that Smalltalk has a much more convenient mechanism. Inner classes in Java are most often used for making up a method on the fly implementing a specific interface. The inner class declaration is only needed to make the compiler happy for type safety. **In Smalltalk, you simply use block closures.** This lets you create behavior on the fly that you can pass around. The system libraries are structured in a way to make use of block closures.

I personally never felt that inner classes were something Smalltalk needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are thinking of using inner classes for tests, then you can also take a look to the class ClassFactoryForTestCase

Answer (score 3):

Creating an anonymous class(es) in smalltalk is a piece of cake.
More than that, any object which has 3 its instance variables properly set to: its superclass, method dictionary and instance format could serve as a class (have instances).
So, i don't see how the problem here.

If you talking about tool(s) support, like browsing or navigating code which contained in such classes, this is different story. Because by default all classes in system are public, and system dictionary is a flat namespace of them (yes , some implementations has namespaces). This simple model works quite well most of the times.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure it could be done with some hacking around the Class and Metaclass protocol. And the question pops quite often from people who have more experience in Java, and Smalltalk becomes interesting to them. Since inner classes have not been implemented inspite of that, I take it to be the sign that most Smalltalk users do not find them usable. This might be because Smalltalk has blocks, which in simpler manner solve many if not all problems that led to the introduction of inner classes to Java.

Answer (score 1):

(a) You could send the messages to create a new class from inside the method of another class

(b) I doubt that there is any benefit in hiding the resulting class from the introspection system

(c) The reason you use inner classes in Java is because there are no first-class functions. If you need to pass a piece of code in Smalltalk, you just pass a block. You don't need to wrap it up with some other type of object to do so.

Comment: There's a great benefit to allowing inner/nested classes: Newspeak uses them to implement its modules. Or, Newspeak's modules (nested classes) are rather a lot like ML's functors (and that's a good thing). The inner class is not hidden from "the introspection system" - it's merely not globally visible.

Comment: @FrankShearar: Perhaps you could elucidate what the benefits are, rather than merely baldly stating that they are great.

Comment: I thought I did: your nested class isn't visible from outside the containing class. All the usual benefits accrue from that encapsulation: loose coupling, explicit dependencies (passed in as parameters when you construct the class). Take a look at the Newspeak papers and Gilad Bracha's blog for extra details.

Comment: @Marcin c) - sometimes there is multiple blocks to pass, and you might want an instance variable there. It would look better if wrapped in a class.

Comment: @milan: I don't see why that would be better than just having multiple parameters to receive multiple blocks, which is in practice what happens.

Comment: Newspeak uses class nesting as its only namespace concept, so that's a little different. I think the need for such small classes tends to be less in Smalltalk, as it's easier to write things generically, and can often be handled by blocks, so people don't feel the need as much. Concrete examples might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (in Squeak at least) comes from the lack of a clean separation of concerns. It's trivial to create your own subclass and put it in a private `SystemDictionary`:

```
myEnv := SystemDictionary new.
myClass := ClassBuilder new
    name: 'MyClass'
    inEnvironment: myEnv
    subclassOf: Object
    type: #normal
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'MyCategory'
    unsafe: false.
```

But even though you put that class in your own `SystemDictionary`, the 'MyCategory' category added to the system navigation (verifiable by opening a `Browser`), and - worse - the class organisers aren't created, so when you navigate to `MyClass` you get a nil pointer.

It's certainly not impossible, theoretically. Right now the tooling's geared towards a single pool of globally visible class definitions.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Gemstone

Comment: I certainly should look at Gemstone. I'm only talking about Squeak in my comment because I looked - briefly - into how to implement a module system. Michael van der Gulik's SecureSqueak looks promising.